# Making text show up on hover and blur effect blinking fix

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-filters

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
body{
background-color:yellow;
}

img{
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

img:hover{
 -webkit-filter:blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0jNI.png">
```

When you hover over the image the borders of the image flash for a bit before settling.. Is there a way to fix that?

And how do i make a text show up on the middle of the image when i hover over it?

Comment: Yeah, it looks "shaky" in Chrome. Odd. Perfectly alright in Mozilla though, at least if you add a `filter` after the `-webkit-filter`... Anyway, to make a text appear, add the text in a span after the filter, position it absolutely, make it invisible using `opacity` and use `img:hover + span` for the selector to show it.

Comment: How do you make it work in firefox? I just tried my code in firefox and it doesn't even work lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: This now looks great in Chrome**

I don't think it's entirely possible to get a super clean transition when using webkit blur. I've had a lot of rendering issues and glitches when using it before. It's a resource hog too when used on a lot of elements. My advice to change your easing to linear and target only the blur. That should tighten it up a little bit.

```
img{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s linear;
    transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s linear;
}
```

As for the text fade in. You'll need to add in an element that is initially `opacity:0;` but then changed to `opacity:1;` when the parent block is hovered. Initial HTML changed to this:

```
<div class='block'>
  <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4">
  <span>Hey there</span>
</div>
```

And the new CSS

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

img {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s linear;
  transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s linear;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
.block img {
  width: 100%;
}
.block span {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.block:hover > span {
  opacity: 1;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

Example here

http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/58d613e80e4a768cc9e54aa1e7aaa0af

Comment: Can you add the code for Firefox as well (`filter` without prefix etc).

Comment: Firefox filter has been added

Comment: The firefox blur doesn't have a 0.5s "transition" time. The rest works though, thank you

Comment: Thank you! Making it `linear` eliminates blinking.